# Autocompleter with sugestions from server

Tags: php, autocomplete, scriptaculous

I want to make an Autocompleter that brings suggestions from the server (the suggestions will appear after you will write the first letter of the word). On the server the words are in a database (a table with words).

I wrote this for the search box

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="scriptaculous/lib/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scriptaculous/src/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
div#sugestii
{width:250px;border:1px solid red}
div#sugestii ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
div#sugestii ul li.selected
{background-color:#ffb;}
div#sugestii ul li
{ cursor:pointer}
</style>
<script>
function initializare()
{
new Ajax.Autocompleter("tbox", "sugestii", "sugestii.php",{})
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initializare()" style="margin:0px">
Caseta de cautare:<br/>
<input type="text" id="tbox"/>
<div id="sugestii"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is sugestii.php

```
<?php
print '<ul><li>first suggestion</li><li>second suggestion</li><li>third suggestion</li></ul>';
?>
```

My problem is that the Autocompleter doesn't work and i don't know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Side note: Is there a specific reason you are using prototype & scriptaculous and not jQuery?

Comment: This is what our teacher recommends. But i think that there is no problem if i would use jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is a much better and more updated JavaScript framework than Prototype. I suggest you use it.
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ should help.

Comment: doesn't work **HOW**?

Comment: With jQuery i made the autocompleter. it's easier.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use a well done solution that actually works: [jquery-ui autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/):

read the doc to set it, for the server side wait for a get parameter named "term" and return a json array (by using the function json_encode on an array for example)

buona fortuna amico mio

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not specified an event yet.

Since is a text input field you can specify an event such as onkeyup or onkeydown and you call the function executing the autocompleter of the scriptaculous (which is a bit wierd)

so

```
{<input type="text" id="tbox" onkeyup="initializare()"/>}
```

But by the way, when in production environment use jquery